# How to fire trigger only once after insert into statement execution (multiple insert)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

How to fire trigger only once after insert into statement execution (single insert into -> multiple insert) ?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server has Statement Triggers, not Row Triggers.  A single INSERT statement will fire a SQL Server trigger only once, even if the INSERT affects multiple rows.

> DML triggers is a special type of stored procedure that automatically
>   takes effect when a data manipulation language (DML) event takes place
>   that affects the table or view defined in the trigger. DML events
>   include INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15